# How to tell MyPy a variable cannot be None after calling a certain method?

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy, python-typing

I'm trying to solve mypy warnings in my project but there are some of them that I cannot really understand. For example, let's take this sample code:

```
from typing import Optional

class Foo:
    data: Optional[str]

    def __init__(self):
        self.data = None

    def IsDataValid(self) -> bool:
        return self.data is not None

    def SetData(self,
                data: str) -> None:
        self.data = data

    def GetData(self) -> str:
        if not self.IsDataValid():
            raise ValueError("Invalid data")
        return self.data
```

To me, it seems obvious that the return type of `GetData` is `str`, since it's not possible to return `None` even if the member is marked as `Optional`.

However, mypy complains that the return type should be `Optional[str]`. The problem is that, if make it `Optional`, it triggers tens of warnings from other classes using that method, because at that point mypy "thinks" that it could return `None`.

I noticed that, if I check directly the member for `None` without using any method:

```
    def GetData(self) -> str:
        if self.data is None:
            raise ValueError("Invalid data")
        return self.data
```

That's fine and I don't get any warning from mypy. I know this solves the problem, but I'd prefer to use a method since it's there for that purpose and I avoid repeating the same check in multiple places.
Is there a way to avoid the warning by using a method to check for `None`?

Comment: What about using a cast:  `return typing.cast(str, self.data)`?

Comment: What about putting the return statement into the else clause? I haven't tried but I think mypy is smart enough to understand that. But first, you need to fix your the if-test.

Comment: Yes sorry, I just mistyped the if the in 2nd snippet. Anyway, it complains also by adding an "else"

Comment: If you add `assert isinstance(self.data, str)` before the `return`, does mypy still protest?

Comment: `assert self.data` should do the trick now before `TypeGuard` will be generally available.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko TypeGuard is generally available now from  the typing-extensions package, which is already a dependency of Mypy